# Query one left table and two right tables UNION result without union operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to join two tables with identical structure to another table with the same join criteria.

I'm also hoping to avoid using UNION for the only reason being that people try not to use union and it's probably doable without it.

Here is a union query that returns the desired result.

```
SELECT     Left_Table.KeyValue, Left_Table.Data_Left1,Left_Table.Data_Left2, UN.KeyValue AS KeyValue2, UN.Data_Right1, UN.Data_Right2
FROM         Left_Table LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT     KeyValue, Data_Right1, Data_Right2
    FROM          Right_Table_1
      UNION
    SELECT     KeyValue, Data_Right1, Data_Right2
    FROM Right_Table_2) AS UN ON Left_Table.KeyValue = UN.KeyValue
```

Here is the result.

```
KeyValue    Data_Left1  Data_Left2  KeyValue2   Data_Right1 Data_Right2
1           Alpha       2016-01-23  1           Grumpy      1812-01-01 
2           beta        2016-01-24  2           Doc         1812-01-01 
2           beta        2016-01-24  2           Donna       2014-12-25 
3           gamma       2015-12-25  3           Rudolph     2015-12-25
```

Here is my attempt at an alternate query without that's not quite right.

```
SELECT     Left_Table.KeyValue, Left_Table.Data_Left1,Left_Table.Data_Left2, COALESCE (RT1.KeyValue, RT2.KeyValue) AS RightKeyvalue, COALESCE (RT1.Data_Right1, RT2.Data_Right1) AS Data_Right1, 
                  COALESCE (RT1.Data_Right2, RT2.Data_Right2) AS Data_Right2
FROM         Left_Table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN    Right_Table_1 AS RT1 ON Left_Table.KeyValue = RT1.KeyValue 
LEFT OUTER JOIN    Right_Table_2 AS RT2 ON Left_Table.KeyValue = RT2.KeyValue
```

The result

```
KeyValue    Data_Left1  Data_Left2  KeyValue2   Data_Right1 Data_Right2
1           Alpha       2016-01-23  1           Grumpy      1812-01-01 
2           beta        2016-01-24  2           Donna       2014-12-25 
3           gamma       2015-12-25  3           Rudolph     2015-12-25
```

Here are some create table and data scripts for testing.Your assistance is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Right_Table_2](
    [KeyValue] [int] NULL,
    [Data_Right1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Data_Right2] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Right_Table_2] ([KeyValue], [Data_Right1], [Data_Right2]) VALUES (1, N'Grumpy', CAST(0xFFFF827200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Right_Table_2] ([KeyValue], [Data_Right1], [Data_Right2]) VALUES (2, N'Doc', CAST(0xFFFF827200000000 AS DateTime))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Right_Table_1](
    [KeyValue] [int] NULL,
    [Data_Right1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Data_Right2] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Right_Table_1] ([KeyValue], [Data_Right1], [Data_Right2]) VALUES (2, N'Donna', CAST(0x0000A40C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Right_Table_1] ([KeyValue], [Data_Right1], [Data_Right2]) VALUES (3, N'Rudolph', CAST(0x0000A57900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Right_Table_1] ([KeyValue], [Data_Right1], [Data_Right2]) VALUES (4, N'Comet', CAST(0x0000A57900000000 AS DateTime))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Left_Table](
    [KeyValue] [int] NULL,
    [Data_Left1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Data_Left2] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Left_Table] ([KeyValue], [Data_Left1], [Data_Left2]) VALUES (1, N'Alpha', CAST(0x0000A59600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Left_Table] ([KeyValue], [Data_Left1], [Data_Left2]) VALUES (2, N'beta', CAST(0x0000A59700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[Left_Table] ([KeyValue], [Data_Left1], [Data_Left2]) VALUES (3, N'gamma', CAST(0x0000A57900000000 AS DateTime))
```

Comment: Can you express in words what your expected result is? If it has "union of" in it, why do you think you should solve it without a `UNION`?

Comment: Honestly TT I don't know. For some reason I have this idea UNIONS are bad and should be avoided like cursors. Perhaps I'm wrong and that UNIONS have their place. The skill being the "when". In direct answer to your question the result should be one row from the Right 1 table and one row from the Right 2 table joined to ONE common row in the left table based on a common Keyvalue in all three tables. The result is two rows with common LEFT table values and different respective Right1 and Right 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of a `UNION` operation would be a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on *all fields* of both tables:

```
SELECT Left_Table.KeyValue, Left_Table.Data_Left1, Left_Table.Data_Left2, 
       UN.KeyValue AS KeyValue2, UN.Data_Right1, UN.Data_Right2
FROM Left_Table LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT COALESCE(t1.KeyValue, t2.KeyValue) AS KeyValue, 
       COALESCE(t1.Data_Right1, t2.Data_Right1) AS Data_Right1,
       COALESCE(t1.Data_Right2, t2.Data_Right2) AS Data_Right2
FROM Right_Table_1 AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Right_Table_2 AS t2  
  ON t1.KeyValue = t2.KeyValue AND 
     t1.Data_Right1 = t2.Data_Right1 AND 
     t1.Data_Right2 = t2.Data_Right2) AS UN
  ON Left_Table.KeyValue = UN.KeyValue
```

I personally find the `UNION` operation preferrable as it is less verbose and is likely to have the same performance as the `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos you answer and advice are appreciated.